# .dae model disappears when approaching

Tags: unity-game-engine

When I move towards my .dae imported model, it disappears. I'm not "inside" the mesh yet, visibly at least, so I don't know what the deal is.

[image]

Comment: Is thesame thing happening in the Game view?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your object is closer than the scene-view camera's "Near Clip Plane", and is not being rendered as a result. The default editor "near clip plane" distance is around 0.3 units, so it shouldn't normally interfere with your objects.

Check that your object scale is correct. If your object is very small, the scene camera's near clip plane will seem much farther in comparison, and will appear to clip objects more aggressively.

You can create a default "Cube" primitive to check the size of your objects. Cubes are 1 unit in all dimensions by default, and most of the time it's a good idea to roughly map one unit to a real-world scale of 1 meter. If your object is considerably smaller than the cube, you may want to try scaling them up and seeing if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

F key is a shortcut key that will automatically zoom and focus to an object. Select the GameObject and press F. This problem should be gone.

If the problem is still there, select the Camera and change the **Clipping Planes** `Near` to 0.3 and `Far` to 50000. You can mess with these values until Object stops disappearing. Although, pressing F should solve it.